# Advanced DataGrid CheckBox

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I have a scenario like, Advanced DataGrid have a checkBox and if i select the header checkBox all the field checkBoxes has to be selected that means multi-select checkBox.

If any one having the sample code, please send me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adobe Cookbook offers a solution for your problem: [Datagrid headerRenderer checkbox to select checkboxes in the row](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Datagrid_headerRenderer_checkbox_to_select_checkbo-7262.html)